# XMLhttp request returns only 250 records from Salesforce (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Appreciate your time and help on this in advance!
I have a problem with MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 request from Excel VBA to get some records (> 250 < 50000) from Salesforce data tables. Looks like my code is all good to retrieve the data except the maximum number of records which is limited to 250. I did a search in the internet, however couldn't find any proper documentation on that yet.
My codes -

```
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")    
sql = sf & "/services/data/v44.0/query/?q=Select col1, col2, col3, col4 from Table Where something = '" & var1 & "' and another = '" & var2 & "'"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", sql, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", " Bearer " & accesscode
xmlhttp.Send
output = xmlhttp.responsetext
```

Can anyone help me to locate some documentation which explain how to enable records more than 250 in this request.
Data table contains > 250 records
Where and Order By criterias already tested.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be hitting a rate limit for your account. Have a look here. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That would be possible, but I am not having access. I have found some workaround, here it is if that help to someone.. There will be attributes at the start of responsetext something like "done":false (if data more than the current fetch) and nextRecordsUrl.. hope this help..